# Windows Explorer columns (in details view) for SVN in Windows 7 (with TortoiseSVN )

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

In Win XP, for my svn repository folders in Windows Explorer, I added an extra column called "SVN Status" (or similar).  I used it to determine which files were modified, added, not versioned, etc.  You can do this by switching to the details view Windows Explorer, right-clicking on the column list, and choosing "More...".

After installing Windows 7, I've noticed that all the SVN column choices are no longer there.  Does anyone have any idea how I can get those options back in again?  Is this an issue with TortoiseSVN?

I'm running the 32-bit version of Windows 7 (fresh install), with the most recent version of TortoiseSVN (TortoiseSVN 1.6.6, Build 17493 - 32 Bit , 2009/10/19 20:22:18).  I've checked the TortoiseSVN options, and I don't see anything so I'm assuming it automatically puts them in as options in Windows Explorer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They're not available in Vista, either....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a known problem with Windows Vista and Windows 7. The explorer no longer supports special/custom columns. See the [TortoiseSVN Columns In Windows Explorer](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#id663427) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Since I skipped Vista I keep forgetting to use it in my search terms.  The missing feature is a HUGE disappointment, I've always used it to help sort out files in large folders :(.

Comment: Yeah, looks like from this link that Custom Column Handlers are supported in XP or earlier.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776831(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Using the "Tortoise SVN - Check for modifications" command is a kind of work around for me concernign this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is now a solution for this although I haven't tried it out myself.

[xplorer²](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/07Feb10-column-handlers-revived.htm)

Comment: I just downloaded it to try it out.  Wish I didn't have to buy a program just for this functionality, but being able to determine the SVN status in a folder with a lot of files is very useful for my job.

Comment: I agree. I've been looking around at potential workarounds for this but haven't found any yet.

Comment: I've been using xplorer2 for about a week now, and it seems to fit the bill.  I am now able to track my SVN status in my folders!  I was still a little hesitant to use a "explorer replacement", but it seems to be the easiest solution.  When installing, I choose to have it NOT replace explorer, so I'm just using it as a separate application.  In the interest of fairness, there also seems to be another product, Total Commander, that also has this feature, but it is more expensive.